# Vaadin demo business app and install on iOS

Tags: android, ios, vaadin

When I look at the [business app](https://labs.vaadin.com/business/) in Chrome (on my PC) or on an android emulator, I can see a link to install the application, but I do not see this option in Firefox (PC) or safari (iPhone).  What enables this ability?

One article I found [here](https://brainhub.eu/library/pwa-on-ios/) suggests that it is an iOS issue, and suggests informing the user of the possibility.

Is this what we would need to do to get it working for devices/browsers that don't show the option automatically?  If so, are there directions out there on how to do it with Vaadin, how to make it easier for them?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Simon's link (and my own link in the post), it looks like iOS does not support this easy install option, which means we have to either add a helpful message telling the user how to do it, or train them, at least until things change with iOS.  I guess, at least for now, we will need to do something similar for the Samsung Internet browser (referenced in Simon's link), and for any other devices our users report not giving them the option.